# Auto Append string to Matched phrases php

Tags: php, preg-match-all

Have got a bit of an issue here, have searched but couldn't find anything similar.

Have got no issues using function like **preg_match_all**  but I want to be able to prePend a string to all it's matches without totally replacing it for instance.

I want to Automatically Add table prefix to all table names in a Query.

Have got this code

```
if(preg_match_all('/((FROM|JOIN) `(.*)`)/', $str, $matches)) {
    $tables = $matches[3];
}
```

which seems to work at least for SELECT & JOIN queries, don't know about other queries yet.
But I want to be able to auto add a particular prefix  to the matched table names; not just list them out,

Any idea; is this even Feasible at all.

Just trying to avoid having to prePend table prefix to table names during queries.

Example inPut:

```
SELECT mail_id, mail_date, mail_from, mail_to, mail_subject, (
            (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM messagecenter_qmails
            WHERE qmail_mail_id = mail_id
            ) + (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM `messagecenter_rels`
            WHERE rel_mail_id = mail_id
            )
            ) AS email_total, (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM `messagecenter_rels`
            WHERE rel_mail_id = mail_id
            ) AS email_sent, (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM `messagecenter_rels`
            INNER JOIN email_receives ON receive_reply_to = rel_sent_id
            WHERE rel_mail_id = mail_id
            ) AS email_reply FROM messagecenter_emails WHERE mail_draft='No' ORDER BY mail_id ASC LIMIT 0,10
```

**Expected outPut:**

```
SELECT mail_id, mail_date, mail_from, mail_to, mail_subject, (
            (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM sys_messagecenter_qmails
            WHERE qmail_mail_id = mail_id
            ) + (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM `sys_messagecenter_rels`
            WHERE rel_mail_id = mail_id
            )
            ) AS email_total, (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM `sys_messagecenter_rels`
            WHERE rel_mail_id = mail_id
            ) AS email_sent, (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM `sys_messagecenter_rels`
            INNER JOIN sys_email_receives ON receive_reply_to = rel_sent_id
            WHERE rel_mail_id = mail_id
            ) AS email_reply FROM sys_messagecenter_emails WHERE mail_draft='No' ORDER BY mail_id ASC LIMIT 0,10
```

You can see the only difference between both codes / queries is the input table names has no prefix e.g  **email_receives**  while the result has table prefix  e.g  **sys_email_receives**

Comment: Can you show an example of the input and the expected output.

Comment: Added **example of the input and the expected output** as requested. Hopefully I wouldn't need to be reminded next time

Comment: Sound like you need `preg_replace`. Here's a [short read](https://infoheap.com/php-preg_replace-back-reference-in-replacement-text/).

Comment: not sure as preg_replace would do string replacement hence if initial match was **Cats** and I wanted to prepend  **My_** to it, it would become  **My_** instead of  **My_Cats** .

What am looking to achieve is Match and prePend so it matches the table name  **Cats** and prepends it with a prefix so we have  **My_Cats**

Comment: Is there any good reason to do it this way, and not parse the string properly? What if a table column (or anything else in your query) contains the substring `FROM` or `JOIN` ?

Comment: @Nico Haase    This among others have been my little worry hence why I came here to get diverse opinions.
I believe the solutions presented so are are much better than capturing the Table names & Using Find and Replace to switch them; I thought of your worry which made me not to use my earlier approach.

My other worry is how to handle other Query types such as INSERT, UPDATE, CREATE, DELETE, DESCRIBE, SHOW, etc queries.

Hopefully someone in here can throw better light on it. I believe my worries & thoughts must have been attempted by someOne else

Comment: So, why not properly parse the query?

Comment: because I didn't know how to; just did a short read up on Query Parsing but don't know much.

Maybe an example of best way to correctly tackle my issue would help.

Have gotten 2 solutions so far Yet am skeptical they wouldn't always work since SQL queries occurs in different forms; my example focuses only on SELECT & JOIN queries.

Answer (score 2):

One option could be using [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with 3 capturing groups.

```
\b(?:FROM|JOIN)\h+\K(`)?([^\s`]+)((?(1)`))(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b(?:FROM|JOIN)\h+\K` Match either FROM or JOIN followed by 1+ horizontal whitespace chars. Then reset the match buffer using `\K`
- `` (`)? `` Optional capture group 1, match a backtick
- `` ([^\s`]+) `` Capture group 2, Match 1+ chars other than a backtick or whtiespace char
- `((?(1)`))` Capture group 3, if clause matching a backtick if group 1 exists
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead, assert a whitespace boundary at the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vFYJcs/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/K4Os1)

In the replacement use the 3 capturing groups with `sys_`

```
$1sys_$2$3
```

For example

```
$result = preg_replace('/\b(?:FROM|JOIN)\h+\K(`)?([^\s`]+)((?(1)`))(?!\S)/', '$1sys_$2$3', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace is the correct function. With Backreferences can recognized parts be reused during replacement.

```
$newSql = preg_replace('~(FROM|JOIN) +`([^`]+)`~','$1 `sys_$2`',$sql);
```

$1 : Character string that was recognized in the first bracket, here FROM or JOIN

$2 : table name

The prefix i set fix.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the solution from @The fourth bird does this.